# Need Http Connection Also WAP Connection

Tags: java-me, midlet, wap, httpconnection

I have code that successfully displays html

```
import java.io.DataInputStream;
import java.io.IOException;

import javax.microedition.io.Connector;
import javax.microedition.io.HttpConnection;
import javax.microedition.lcdui.Command;
import javax.microedition.lcdui.CommandListener;
import javax.microedition.lcdui.Display;
import javax.microedition.lcdui.Displayable;
import javax.microedition.lcdui.Form;
import javax.microedition.lcdui.StringItem;
import javax.microedition.lcdui.TextField;
import javax.microedition.midlet.MIDlet;


public class Example extends MIDlet implements CommandListener {
.
.
.
.
.

private String requestUsingGET(String URLString) throws IOException {
    HttpConnection hpc = null;
    DataInputStream dis = null;
    boolean newline = false;
    String content = "";
    try {
      hpc = (HttpConnection) Connector.open(URLString);
      dis = new DataInputStream(hpc.openInputStream());
      int character;

      while ((character = dis.read()) != -1) {
        if ((char) character == '\\') {
          newline = true;
          continue;
        } else {
          if ((char) character == 'n' && newline) {
            content += "\n";
            newline = false;
          } else if (newline) {
            content += "\\" + (char) character;
            newline = false;
          } else {
            content += (char) character;
            newline = false;
          }
        }

      }
      if (hpc != null)
        hpc.close();
      if (dis != null)
        dis.close();
    } catch (IOException e2) {
    }

    return content;
  }
}
```

But other than I want to display `WAP.what` to add on this in my code? 
To display the WAP browser.

Because when I tried to address `wap.yahoo.com` is not in response by the system.

Comment: You should check the result of HttpConnection.getResponseCode() before opening the DataInputStream. Post it here if you're still stuck after that.

Comment: im sorry i still stuck ... can u re write that code with ur idea